# Angular 2 AOT "Expression form not supported" error

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

In Angular 2 I would like to use the hash strategie only for IE9. For that I configure the router to use the hash strategy only if I detect the IE9 browser.

This was working when compiling with tsc:

```
const useHash: boolean = (typeof window.history.pushState) !== 'function';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {initialNavigation : false, useHash : useHash})
  ]
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

However the ngc compiler (AOT compilation) does not accept it. The following error is thrown by ngc (on the const declaration line).

> Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported

I have also tried (based on this article: https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5#.h4pnszi13):

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {initialNavigation : false, useHash : AppModule.useHash})
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  static useHash: boolean = (typeof window.history.pushState) !== 'function';
}
```

But I get the same error (on the provider line this time). Note that it works if I do `static useHash: boolean = false;`.

How can I solve the issue for the module declaration?

Answer (score 0):

If you just export the `useHash` function (from the first code snippet) it should work. See the code snippet bellow:

```
export function useHash() {
  return (typeof window.history.pushState) !== 'function';
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {initialNavigation : false, useHash : useHash})
  ]
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but no it does not work. I get `Argument of type '{ initialNavigation: false; useHash: () => boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ExtraOptions'.
  Types of property 'useHash' are incompatible.`. If I try with `useHash: useHash()` I get the original error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is indeed strange, the AOT compiler is a bit limited in getting the full picture because of TS limitation that should be solved soon.

You can track this issue for updates
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13138

To workaround your issue you just need to play a little trick on the angular compiler...

```
const rConfig = { useHash: true, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules };
rConfig.useHash = (typeof window.history.pushState) !== 'function';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, rConfig)
  ]
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```